# Best way to generate all possible bidirectional graphs Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to generate all possible bidirectional graphs given a set of nodes. I'm storing my graphs as numpy vectors, and need them that way as there is some downstream code consumes the graphs in this format.

Lets say I have two sets of nodes in which nodes in the same set do not connect. It is however possible to have graphs in which members of two sets do not meet at all.

```
posArgs= [0,1]      # (0->1) / (1->1) is not allowed..neither is (0->1)
negArgs= [2]        # (0->2) is possible, and so is (0 2) - meaning no connection.
```

To illustrate what I mean:

[image]

translates as:

```
import numpy as np
graph = np.array([0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0])
singleGraph= np.vstack( np.array_split(np.array(graph), nargs))

>>[[0 0 1]
[0 0 1]
[0 0 0]]
# Where the first row represent node 0's relationships with nodes 0, 1, 2
# the second row represents node 1's relationships with nodes 0, 1, 2 etc
```

What I want is to generate all the possible ways in which these two sets can then be constructed (i.e. all the possible node combinations as vectors). At the moment I am using itertools.product to generate a power set of all the nodes, then I create a bunch of vectors in which there are circular connections and same set connections. I then delete them from the powerset. Hence using the sets above I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

posArgs= [0,1]      # 0->1 / 1->1 is not allowed..neither is 0->1
negArgs= [2]

nargs= len(posArgs+ negArgs)
allPermutations= np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1], repeat=nargs*nargs)))

# Create list of Attacks that we will never need. Circular attacks, and attacks between arguments of same polarity
circularAttacks = (np.arange(0, nargs*nargs, nargs+1)).tolist()
samePolarityAttacks = []
posList = list(itertools.permutations(posArgs, 2))
negList = list(itertools.permutations(negArgs, 2))
totList = posList + negList

for l in totList:
    ptn = ((l[0]+1)*nargs)- ((nargs+1) - l[1]) + 1 # All the odd +1 are to account for the shift in 0 index
    samePolarityAttacks.append(ptn)


graphsToDelete = np.unique([circularAttacks + samePolarityAttacks])
subGraphs = allPermutations[:,graphsToDelete]
cutDownGraphs = np.delete(allPermutations, (np.where(subGraphs>0)[0]).tolist(), axis = 0)

for graph in cutDownGraphs:
    singleGraph= np.vstack( np.array_split(np.array(graph), nargs))
    print(singleGraph)
```

My problem is that when I have more than 5 nodes within both of my sets my itertools.product is trying to produce (2^25) set of vectors. This of course is really expensive and leaves me with memory leaks.

Are you aware of a smart way in which I can reshape this code while ensuring my graphs stay in this numpy array format?

--Additional info:

For two sets, one node a set, all possible combinations look as follows:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You really need to try to keep everything iterators or `itertools` doesn't save you any memory.  I don't understand the code well enough to untangle it, but using `itertools.chain.from_iterable(a,b)` instead of `list(a)+list(b)` and `itertools.dropwhile()` instead of `np.delete` will allow you to iterate without building huge data structures behind your code.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes cycles are ruled out. But it is not really a tree..its an acyclic bi-directional graph. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for adjusting the comments..I'd misunderstood your question. No cycles are not ruled out...I meant to say that circular connections are not allowed...meaning there cannot be a line going from node 0 to node 0..apologies

Comment: Hi Paul...no. There are two sets, there can only be lines going between different sets. As 0 and 1 are in the same set, they cannot have lines between them. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Hi Paul...I've added a pic to the bottom of the question to illustrate the point. Apologies I have to run it in Latex as not familiar with any other bidirectional graph drawing tools. Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, they are always allowed. You can see in the example I gave, there are only those combos that can happen

Comment: Hi Paul, no sorry I had made a mistake, in my copy paste...I've shortened the graph with now two nodes to see if this helps. But you were right there should have been more graphs

Comment: Hi Paul..this is quite embarrassing. I've adjusted again (hopefully) for the last time

Comment: I hate to say this, but now it's not as useful as it could be, since it only shows self-connections are forbidden. Everything else is allowed in this example.

Comment: Nice pure Python data structures for graphs in https://www.amazon.ca/Python-Algorithms-Mastering-Basic-Language/dp/1430232374. Much faster than using Numpy (for graphs, I mean) in my experience. There are some PDFs floating around.